# HTTPS to HTTPS reverse proxy with nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, proxy, https

I have an Apache webserver configures with an SSL certificate. I have to put it behind a proxy, from some reasons.
I'd like to configure the proxy (nginx?) to works as simple relay, from HTTPS to HTTPS, as simple as possible.

My questions are:

- is HTTPS to HTTPS proxy a good idea?
- if so, do I need to give the proxy the SSL certificate too or can I just enable SSL in nginx/apache/whatever's parameters?

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

> is HTTPS to HTTPS proxy a good idea?

Depends on the situation/use-case/reasoning, there's no one-fits-all answer for that.

> if so, do I need to give the proxy the SSL certificate too or can I just enable SSL in nginx/apache/whatever's parameters?

**Yes** and **No**!

You have two ways of doing this:

1. SSL Reverse Proxy
2. TCP Load Balancing

**SSL Reverse Proxy**

Certificates **are** needed on the load balancer, you set up a HTTPS proxy and all HTTPS connections to the load balancer are terminated there before being proxied to the backends and the HTTPS re-applied if your backend supports it.

**TCP Load Balancing**

You **do not** need SSL certificates on the load balancer. The connections are distributed at the TCP layer, the SSL content is ignored/unmodified and just passed through. Your backend needs to be HTTPS ready with the SSL certs etc.

Hopefully this will set you in the right direction...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Since I do not need load balancing but a simple HTTP(S) redirection based on subdomain name, what youd you recommend? note: all my backends use Apache to serve WebUIs.